# What are tracked files and untracked files in the context of Git?

Tags: git, git-track, git-untracked

I'm new to Git. I wish to know what are *tracked* and *untracked* files?
I read "Pro Git", but still couldn't quite understand.

Can someone explain to me the difference between the two by providing an example?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A file is tracked if it is under version control.

As a small example, a C++ project would have

```
Makefile
main.cpp
interface.hpp
worker.cpp
```

as source files; you'd put these under version control. During build,

```
main.o
worker.o
myapp
```

are generated; these do not belong under version control, so you do not use `git add` on them. They remain *untracked*, because git does not care what happens to them. Until you add them to `.gitignore` (the .o files are ignored by default), git does not known whether you want to add or ignore them, so it displays them with the `git status` command until you make a decision.

Whether a file is tracked or not also depends on the version -- suppose you autogenerate `worker.cpp` and remove it from version control at a later version. The file is now untracked in that version. When you go back to a version where the file was still under version control, git will refuse to overwrite that file during checkout.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would want to deal with untracked files for long, either they are tracked or they belong in gitignore....what is the purpose of untracked files that don't get mentioned in gitignore?

Comment: What do you mean by `git will refuse to overwrite that file during checkout.`

Answer (score 16):

The [Git Pro book chapter](http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html) you mention tries to detail the notion of untracked file:

When you checkout a given SHA1, you get a "snapshot" of all versioned files.
**Any file not referenced by this snapshot is untracked**. It isn't part of the Git tree:
See "[git - how to tell if a file is git tracked (by shell exit code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405305/git-how-to-tell-if-a-file-is-git-tracked-by-shell-exit-code)"

Any file that you want to ignore must be untracked (as explained in this [GitHub help page](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/)).

> Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a rule was added to the `.gitignore` file to ignore it.
> In such a case the file must be un-tracked, usually with `git rm --cached filename`

[image: File Status Lifecycle]

Comment: add untracked file will add it to staging area, the arrow should point to staged instead of unmodified

Comment: what is the file you mention in "this file" phrase. is it .gitignore? Also @englealuze is right, here is the correct image link : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/lifecycle.png

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor The `.gitignore` file: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

Tracked files are the one handled (version controlled) by Git, that were once added and committed. Untracked files are most of the time files you don't want to be controlled, because for example they are generated by your compiler.

You add untracked files to the `.gitignore` file, so that Git don't ask you if you want to track them.

Comment: It is entirely incorrect to say that a "tracked file" is one that was once added AND COMMITTED. A tracked file is simply a file that exists in the index tree--how it got there could have been due to a branch checkout or due to an add or due to a direct Git plumbing command.

Answer (score 7):

From a purely technical perspective: A tracked file is simply a file that exists in the Git index. To say it's a file "under version control" is misleading, because this suggests that it's a file that made it into the repo--and that's not necessary for a file to be tracked.

When you init a new Git repo, the index is empty and all files in your working directory are untracked. A file gets tracked when it's added to the index--at which point a SHA-1 hash is created for it and an object entry is placed into the .Git\Objects folder. From that moment on, Git is able to compare the contents/name of the same file in the working directory in order to track changes, renames, and deletes. As long as the file exists in the index, it is tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that each file in your working directory can be in one of two states: tracked or untracked. In short, tracked files are files that Git knows about. Untracked files are everything else — any files in your working directory that were not in your last snapshot and are not in your staging area. Tracked files are files that were in the last snapshot; they can be unmodified, modified, or staged

Comment: Do you mean that untracked files tend most of the times to be new files in the wirking tree?

Answer (score 1):

- **Tracked** : *Files which u maked them 'git add' or 'git commit' (i mean this files already is under control of git)*
- **Untracked** : *Files which u not maked them 'git add' or 'git commit' (if u added or committed an X file - this means git tracking that X file)*
- *When you first time adding files to an Working Directory, they are all untracked. To get Git to track them, you need to stage them(git add) or add them to the local repository(git commit)*

Answer (score 1):

Tracked Files:

Tracked files are files that Git is aware of and actively manages. These are files that have been added to the Git repository using the git add command and committed with git commit. Git tracks changes to these files, allowing you to see the history of changes, switch between different versions (commits), and share these changes with others through pushes to remote repositories.

Untracked Files:

Untracked files are files that are not currently being managed by Git. These are typically files that exist in the working directory of your repository but have not been added to the Git repository using git add. Untracked files will not be included in commits, and Git will not keep a history of changes to these files until you explicitly add them to the repository using git add.

You can use the git status command to see a list of tracked and untracked files in your repository. Tracked files will appear under the "Changes to be committed" section, while untracked files will appear under the "Untracked files" section.