# How can I have git ignore the root level .vs directory?

Tags: git, ignore

I know that git (as of 1.8.2) will ignore entire directories (e.g. "bin") at any level using a .gitignore file (in the root directory) that contains something like:

bin/

However, that doesn't seem to work for:

.vs/

Is there special syntax for directories that begin with "."?

Comment: Exactly what you say doesn't work works fine for me. Check for typos, or something like that?

Comment: `.vs/` should work you can also try `/.vs/` if .vs is in the project root.

Comment: Does your gitignore have any lines for suo files that might unignore it? Or maybe it was already tracked?

Comment: This file was already being tracked.  Removing it from the repo is what actually resolved it.  Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there special syntax for directories that begin with "`.`"?

I confirm there is nothing special.

If `git ls-files -- .vs/a_file_name` returns anything (see "[How to tell if a file is git tracked (by shell `exit` code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2405305/6309)"), then you need, as you have seen, to remove it first:

```
git rm --cached -r -- .vs/
```

Then a `git status` should not bring anything from `.vs/`