# Find which git commit deleted "directory" (not file)?

Tags: git

[Not a duplicate please. I've found many similar questions on here, none which helped.]

I'm working on a project I haven't touched in many months, but another user has been working on it a lot and deleted the src directory.

What git command would return the id of the commit that deleted that folder?.

`REPO/.git`

**`REPO/html/src`**

I've tried these commands among others but can't nail it:

`git log --full-history -- html/src`

`git log --full-history -- ./html/src`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32465358/6309 is pretty close, though.

Comment: Git doesn't store directories; Git only stores files. If a commit deletes the last file *in* a directory, the directory itself vanishes in the process. If a commit adds a file *in* a directory, Git makes the directory automatically.