# How to skip files belonging to a git submodule?

Tags: bash, git, macos

I would like to mass-update files in a script, using the following command:

```
grep -l -r -E "..." . | while read -r FILE ; do
    # How to do the next line only for files that are not in submodules?
    sed -i '' -E '...' "${FILE}"
done
```

However, I have git submodules and do not want to update files contained in those submodules. Short of maintaining a blacklist of paths where the submodules are, is there any way to check if a file belongs to a submodule or skip them altogether?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405305/how-to-tell-if-a-file-is-git-tracked-by-shell-exit-code

Comment: The problem with that approach is that all the files are tracked, just in a submodule rather than the main repo.

Comment: You could use `git grep` rather than regular grep.

Comment: @torek It works exactly as I need. Care to add an answer?

Comment: Technically, it's not an answer to the question you *asked*. :-) (The linked question *is*, and should work: the test for "is a tracked file" will use the *current* Git repo's index, not the submodule repo's index. It's just less efficient than not looking at submodule files in the first place.)

Comment: I changed the question. Your answer is what I _needed_. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `git grep` directly—Git's grep is pretty capable, but there may be minor differences from the system variant to watch out for—this sidesteps the problem nicely since `git grep` only looks at the right files in the first place.

(Mostly, it should just be a matter of replacing `grep` with `git grep`.)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did have to change the grep step a little bit, but it works as expected.