# Most efficient way to get the path of a git repo which tracks a file

Tags: git, inotify, inotifywait

I am watching an arbitrary folder with inotifywait. When a file changes, I want to determine which git repo (if any) is relevant to that file.

I see this answer:
[How to tell if a file is git tracked (by shell exit code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405305/how-to-tell-if-a-file-is-git-tracked-by-shell-exit-code)

The difference here is - I don't really care if git is tracking the file or not, I just want to know - if git *were* to track that file, which git existing git repo would it be for. That is my question.

Is the best way to do this simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$(dirname "$changed_file")" && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

? is that about right? will that `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` command always given the relevant repo for that file?

Comment: yes, you have the correct command. @jthill's answer mentions that technically, there may be some weirder setups, and gives pointers to where to find information about that, but `rev-parse --show-toplevel` will be the correct way on all regular setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if git were to track that file, which git existing git repo would it be for.

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` will show you the top of the work tree for the repo that would track a file you `git add` from there, yes, but Git doesn't impose any requirements on where a repository's parts are kept. There's a search path for the ones you don't call out explicitly, and `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` is showing you the work tree it found, if you didnt' tell it, or the one you told it to use.  Say `git help` to see the main options for getting explicit with it, and pointers to further docs if you need them.