# why files inside .gitignore are getting added with "git add ." command & pushed to repo first commit?

Tags: github

I've added few files in `.gitignore` but doing `git add .` first time and committing, pushing pushes even files which should have been ignored

```
#Sensitive Data
aws-exports.js
aws-exports-dev.js
aws-exports-main.js
.env
```

I saw these files getting committed to GH repo

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your `.gitignore` file to the question.

Comment: Were these files already tracked at that point?  Are you on a case-insensitive operating system and do those files differ in case from what's in `.gitignore`?

Comment: How to find if files are already tracked ? I'm on Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

> How to find if files are already tracked ? I'm on Mac OS

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406813/6309):

```sh
git ls-files --error-unmatch <file name>
echo $?
```

- If this prints 0, there was no error, meaning the file was tracked by Git. - If it prints 1, then the file was not tracked by Git.

Also:

```
git check-ignore -v -- aFile_that_should_be_ignored
```

If it prints nothing while you know if should be ignored, it means it is already tracked:

```
git rm --cached -- aFile_that_should_be_ignored
git check-ignore -v -- aFile_that_should_be_ignored
```

This time, your `.gitignore` rule should be displayed.

Note that you can create a GitHub repository from command-line (locally), with a `.gitignore` template (from [`github/gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore)), using `gh repo create --gitignore=xxx` ([PR 3746](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/3746)).

Then you would clone your GitHub repository, and start working in it: any file that should be ignored would be, since none would have yet been tracked in that new local clone.